# Font awesome component not working inside vue custom elements

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, font-awesome, webpack-5

I have a vue 3 project, Where I created a custom element. But font-awesome component is not working inside that custom element.

main.ts

```
import {createApp, defineCustomElement} from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router.ts';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome';
import MyElement from './component/MyElement.ce.vue';

const myCustomElement = defineCustomElement(MyElement);
customElements.define(`my-custom-element`, myCustomElement);
const app = createApp(App);

app.use(router);
app.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon);

app.mount("#app");
```

App.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <my-custom-element />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name:'MainApp'
}
</script>
```

./component/MyElement.ce.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>my element should work with icon</h1>
       <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-brands fa-twitter" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { faTwitter } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';

library.add(faTwitter);
export default {
    name: "MyElement",
}
</script>

<style>
    h1{
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main.ts'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
  },
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: {
      rewrites: [
        { from: /.*/, to: path.join('./', 'index.html') },
      ],
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options:{
          compilerOptions:{
            isCustomElement: (tag) => tag.includes('-')
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: {
          appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["css-loader"],
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, './index.html'),
      inject: 'body',
     }),
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^3.0.2",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.41",
    "fine-uploader": "^5.16.2",
    "fine-uploader-wrappers": "^1.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.1",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "vue": "^3.2.41",
    "vue-loader": "^17.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.6",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^6.7.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development"
  }
}
```

Everything works including the style but FontAwesomeIcon is not working as it is supposed to.

This is what it shows in the browser
[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is an npm package [vue3-webcomponent-wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-webcomponent-wrapper). I implemented it and used i tag of font-awesome which solved my issue. I don't know if this is the perfect solution but this is the only solution I found.

Comment: post your answers too.. how did you implement it? and  how did it solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

checkout if your icon available in fontawesome version 6.2.1

Comment: It is available and the icon works in other components as expected. It just doesn't work in custom elements. Any idea why?

Comment: this should be posted as a comment, not an answer.